# EF classes don't show up in when adding new API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This question has been asked a few times in SO but nothing helped so far in my case.

To an existing MVC project I added a model generated from a database (using database first). Now I would like to add a new API controller. However, neither my new model classes nor my data context class show up in "Add Controller" dialog:

- made sure I recompiled my dll
- restarted VS (2010)
- deleted AssemblyInfo.cs (as suggested in another SO post)
- checked with ILSpy to make sure models are in and have an Id

My workaround is to put my models in another dll. However, I think that shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: Did you try to Clean the project or even delete both the bin and obj folders; followed by a rebuild?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, first Clean() and then Rebuild().

Comment: But did you also try and manually delete the `obj` and `bin` folders?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as a namespace or reference issue.

If they are in different projects then the controller project will eed to reference the respository project.

Can you get to the models by using the full namespace path - you made just need to add a suitable `using` in the class; typing CTRL+. will give you suggestions.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: If my models are in another dll it works. If the they are in the same project I made sure (using ILSpy) the namespace is correct. I also tried by manually typing the FQN when adding a new controller.

Comment: I am confused by your reference to DLLs; I always work at the project level. Perhaps some sample code would help showing where the problem is